# "Incorrect number of dimensions" error when indexing in R

Tags: r, indexing, statistics

I was analyzing some results for my thesis for a second time as I had new data, I used the dunntest() function and obtained a table like this:

```
Comparison          Z      P.unadj        P.adj
1  D20FN30K - D20FN60K -1.7340246 8.291372e-02 1.160792e-01
2  D20FN30K - D20MG30K  1.3602563 1.737488e-01 2.211349e-01
3  D20FN60K - D20MG30K  3.0942809 1.972906e-03 3.068965e-03
```

However when I try to index it to have only the P-value by typing PT[,4] it gives me an error saying "incorrect number of dimension".
I am using the same code as I did the first time when it worked, now it suddenly doesn't.

Comment: Can you please include the output from `dput(PT)` (assuming it is just as above, a few rows)? It may help suggest why that would happen (I suspect it's actually a `list` internally, so `[,4]` matrix-like indexing will not work). Further, I cannot find `dunntest`. I can find `dunn.test::dunn.test`, `FSA::dunnTest`, and `DescTools::DunnTest`; which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to perform dunntest using the dunnTest function from FSA package and the issue according to me is that the output of your function is not a dataframe or a matrix.

You need to extract the result dataframe from the output

Here is the data simulated for the test: (from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FSA/versions/0.8.32/topics/dunnTest)

```
ponds <- data.frame(pond=as.factor(rep(1:4,each=8)),
                    pH=c(7.68,7.69,7.70,7.70,7.72,7.73,7.73,7.76,
                         7.71,7.73,7.74,7.74,7.78,7.78,7.80,7.81,
                         7.74,7.75,7.77,7.78,7.80,7.81,7.84,NA,
                         7.71,7.71,7.74,7.79,7.81,7.85,7.87,7.91))
ponds2 <- ponds[complete.cases(ponds),]
```

If i run the test I get this:

```
    > dunnTest(ponds2$pH,ponds2$pond)
Dunn (1964) Kruskal-Wallis multiple comparison
  p-values adjusted with the Holm method.

  Comparison           Z     P.unadj      P.adj
1      1 - 2 -2.13700630 0.032597479 0.13038992
2      1 - 3 -2.94934889 0.003184443 0.01592221
3      2 - 3 -0.88480467 0.376261991 1.00000000
4      1 - 4 -2.99180882 0.002773299 0.01663979
5      2 - 4 -0.85480252 0.392660483 0.78532097
6      3 - 4  0.05898698 0.952962480 0.95296248
```

To extract the p-value I did this:

```
a =dunnTest(ponds2$pH,ponds2$pond)
a = a$res
a$P.adj
```

I hope it helped